# О формате scanf

Tags: c, строки

Что должна считать функция `sscanf` в этом случае?

```
sscanf(gBufRx, "%hu", &x);
```

Передается строка вида `xxx` или `0xx` (десятичные). `x` - `unsigned short`.

Проверил бы, но программа на контроллере и нет возможности посмотреть, что там творится.

Складывается впечатление, что если передавать строку вида `xxx` (например, 155), то все нормально, а если первый 0 (например, 090), то читается какое-то большое число.
Что у меня неправильно?

Comment: Единственная догадка, приходящая в голову - у Вас указатель gBufRx в случае **0хх** смотрит не туда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно этому - [scanf Width Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d(v=VS.100).aspx) - должно читаться unsigned short int. И явной проблемы нет. Разве что неведомым мне образом число, начинающееся с нуля трактуется как в восьмеричной системе...

Comment: ну почему неведомым образом. если вначале ноль - то это и есть восьмеричное число. Все четко по стандарту.
Но как компилятор кушает 090 - для меня загадка.

Comment: У меня что с ведущим нулем, что без него считывает десятичные и все нормально. MinGW gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3) Windows 7.

Comment: Неведомым, т.к. одно дело числовые литералы, которые обрабатывает компилятор (и он различает 10, 010 и 0x10), а другое дело - ф-ция `scanf` и ее производные, которые не занимаются автоматическим преобразованием между разными системами счисления.

Comment: Ошибки были немного не там. Теперь читается нормально. Формат десятичный.